# Ubuntu 18.04 Login Keyboard Language English (US) and Afghan?

Tags: keyboard, login, keyboard-layout, language-support

I'd like to report something that just happened to me and apparently there is no solution found online.

After a system update, today I booted my laptop and I found out that my password was not working. Since it's spelled with italian vowels (with the accent) I was thinking that I typed it wrong but...

After a quick check, I noticed the the only languages available on the login screen are English (US) and Afghan.

So I had to reset my password with the Safe Mode boot.

Once I managed to finally access my desktop, all languages were correctly set to Italian.

And, for some reasons (unrelated?), Google acts like all cookies were deleted.

Anyway, my login screen still has those two stupid keyboard layouts that nobody wanted.

Could you please help? I'm desperate! Thanks!

Comment: So, I could not find a solution in the short term, so I replaced gdm3 with lightdm and I must say that, for the moment, it works great. I hope that in the future there will be a solution to the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when being Spanish speaking and using the letter ñ in my passwords. Finally I made the same decision to replace the manager start, gdm3 by LightDM, with a small point: at first, LightDM login screen remained in infinite loop, even getting good password, but change the startup type from Ubuntu Wayland to Ubuntu (default) and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with french (several applications in English  but some were in french with the french keyboard layout, some applications did not even start). It took me several steps to fix it completely:

- reinstallation of the `language-pack-fr` package
- regeneration of the locales: `sudo locale-gen --lang en` and `sudo locale-gen --lang fr`
- reconfiguration of the locales: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` (I checked 'all locales')
- check with Ubuntu `Region and Language` tool (click on `Apply system-wide`)

Note that this was a trial and error process: I did those steps several times in various order rebooting to test. So it's not a step-by-step recipe.

For this particular problem (the last one), I think I solved it by re-installing the `gdm` package (with synaptic). I removed the QWERTY keyboard layout first (I don't know if it is needed).

Comment: I tried all of your steps - but no luck. I still only see English and Afghani. This is a major bug in Ubuntu. Why are so few complaining? :(

Comment: I agree it's a boring problem. I'm sorry if my message could not help. As I said, I tried those things not in order. Maybe retry them. Otherwise, reinstalling from scratch is usually doable (provided you backup critical data).

Answer (score 1):

Alright - I had the same problem after upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04.

The solution I found was to remove my keyboard language (German) from the settings completely, switch everything to English (US) only. Everything in the region&language settings.
After that did a restart - and voila: only English was available.

After that, I re-installed the German keyboard settings and set that as the default - logged out and on again. Now it's fine, Afghani is gone, German is back again.

Answer (score 0):

I add the exact same issue with only English(US) and Afghani being available when upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

You can change the keyboard for the login screen from the "Region & Language" menu.

There is a specific menu called "**Login Screen**" at the top right in the window, which is not obvious at first look.

There, you can configure the language and keyboard for the Login screen.

See below

[image]

Comment: how did you get this  "Login Screen"  menu? I don't have it on same Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (((

Comment: @StanFad : I have no idea this was on by default on my system...